# XCode view c++ class member in debugger?

Tags: xcode, variables, debugging

I just can't see c++ class member value while I moved mouse on it. For locally variables it works fine, and off course I can see class member values in Debugger (separated window) but it's not so comfortable.

This problem wasn't in xcode 3.0 version... (only >3.0)

P.S. I am sure that I am on Debug not Release project.

Answer (score 0):

Expand this in debugger and you will see member variables.

Comment: Yea I know but I want to see value while move mouse on it. Every time I should expand "this" - it's very annoying.
In older xcode (3.0) it worked well (like in Visual Studio - move mouse on any variable and you will see it's value).

Comment: I use xcode for about 4 years and I never saw a member variable on mouse over:)

Comment: I think I found crux of the problem. It's source file extension. When I use .mm I can't see class members (expression window say it's: "out of scope"), but when I use .cpp it works!
The main problem now is that I need to use objective-c and c++ mixed so I must use .mm :/

@Felics so are you always expand 'this' in debugger? :)

Comment: Yes. When I was using Visual Studio and Xcode it was a problem, but now I'm used with this and it doesn't bother me anymore...